# How do I delete spaces between capitalized words using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my option:

```
<option value="Kabardino-Balkar Republic">Kabardino-Balkar Republic</option>
<option value="Karachay-Cherkess Republic">Karachay-Cherkess Republic</option>
<option value="Karelia Republic">Karelia Republic</option>
<option value="Komi Republic">Komi Republic</option>
<option value="Mari El Republic">Mari El Republic</option>
<option value="Mordovia Republic">Mordovia Republic</option>
```

.. and I want them to be in the following format:

```
<option value="Kabardino-BalkarRepublic">Kabardino-Balkar Republic</option>
<option value="Karachay-CherkessRepublic">Karachay-Cherkess Republic</option>
<option value="KareliaRepublic">Karelia Republic</option>
<option value="KomiRepublic">Komi Republic</option>
<option value="MariElRepublic">Mari El Republic</option>
<option value="MordoviaRepublic">Mordovia Republic</option>
```

How can I delete the spaces between capitalized words in the `value` attribute while keeping the hyphens in tact?

Comment: Please note the edits I made to your question for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('option').val(function(i, val){
  return val.split(" ").join("")
})
```

[→](http://jsfiddle.net/6yG6h/)

Comment: May I ask what actually have you done, I didn't see any changes in options.

Comment: @SheikhHeera You can inspect the attributes of option elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just use regex with the string replace method?

```
$('option').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.val($this.val().replace(/\s/g,'')); // <-- replace a space with no space
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XgNJV/

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done bins for above issue. you can check demo link as well.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7o

**HTML**

```
<select id="demo">
  <option value="Kabardino-Balkar Republic">
    Kabardino-Balkar Republic
  </option>
  <option value="Karachay-Cherkess Republic">
    Karachay-Cherkess Republic
  </option>
  <option value="Karelia Republic">
    Karelia Republic
  </option>
  <option value="Komi Republic">
    Komi Republic
  </option>
  <option value="Mari El Republic">
    Mari El Republic
  </option>
  <option value="Mordovia Republic">
    Mordovia Republic
  </option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#demo option").each(function() {
        var $option = $(this);
        $option.val($option.val().replace(/([A-Za-z0-9-_])\s([A-Z]{1})/g, '$1$2'));
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7o